# what is the best way to access the private data in my iterator class and not break the encapsulation?

Tags: c++

I have a class like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Store {

private:
    struct pointNode {
        T data;
        pointNode* next;
        pointNode* prev;

        pointNode() :data(0), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}
        pointNode(T n_data) : data(n_data), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}

        const T& getValue() {
            return this->data;
        }


    };
    pointNode* head;
    pointNode* tail;

public:

    class Iterator {
        using Iterator_type = Store<T>::pointNode;
    public:
        Iterator() = default;

        Iterator(Iterator_type* rNode) {
            current_node = rNode;
        }

    private:
        Iterator_type* current_node;

    };

};
```

I need to get

```
Iterator_type* current_node;
```

What is the correct way to get this data field?
I understand that you can do something like this:

```
friend class Store;
```

inside the iterator class.But is this considered normal, or is there a more beautiful way?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to do this is to add an accessor function, like this:

```
class Iterator
{
public:
    Iterator_type* get_current_node() const {
        return current_node;
    }

private:
    Iterator_type* current_node;
};
```

---

PS: Note that the default constructor `Iterator() = default;` leaves `current_node` data member uninitialized.

Comment: Wouldn't the user then be able to access the private data?I just want to prevent the user from accessing the pointer when inserting this file.

Comment: @Alpharius Of course he will. You either give access or you don't. The accessor at least restricts what kind of access you give (i.e. in this case - read only) and to which members. If you only want to give access to one class or function then `friend` is your only option, but it will allow all access to all private and protected members to the friend.